# Just upgraded to 12.10, and cannot enable VirtualBox driver

Tags: drivers, virtualbox, 12.10

After upgrading to 12.10 and installing VirtualBox guest additions, they cannot be enabled in the **Additional Drivers** pane.

If I click the only available option, "Continue using a manually installed driver, the **Apply changes** button will stay grayed out, and the current selection seems to be *Do 
not use the device* (though it's grayed out.)

Any idea about this?

Comment: I think you running virtualbox 1.x version upgrading to 2.x might solve the issue. Try out

Comment: 1.x, 2.x? Are you talking about the actual virtualbox in my host system? That's 4.1.20.

Comment: oops sorry. Yes upgrade virtualbox to 4.2. https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upgrading virtual box will solve this issue.

Download virtual box 4.2 from [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads). Uninstall and reinstall the guest additions.

Here is the changelog of 4.2.2 related to Linux

> - Linux hosts / guests: Linux 3.7-rc1 fixes
> - Linux Additions: support X.Org Server 1.13
> - Linux Additions: fixed a hang when the X server was restarted with old guest kernels
> - Linux Additions: fixed a VBoxService crash during CPU hot remove

Answer (score 1):

There is a forum post on the VirtualBox forum directly related to Ubuntu Desktop 12.10 and getting 3D acceleration working properly.  There are definitely some mixed results.

[Ubuntu 12.10 "Virtually" Unusable](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=51727&sid=36c95f58983d1295a120092fe6b8c85c&start=45)